# Background Image width 100% height auto

Tags: css

I want to achieve the same as

```
<img src="..">
img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

with an `background-image`. After fiddling around with it for ages I just don't have any ideas left. What I've tried is in the snippet below as `article header .logo`

What I actually want to do: Let the image be 100% wide of the parent (considering paddings) and scale the image height automatically. But instead using a `img` I want to do it with a `div` and `background-image`.

If my image is 100px wide and 50px height and my parent container is 1000px wide (no paddings) the image should be 1000px wide and 500px height to keep the aspect ratio of the image.

---

Here my snippet

```css
article header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

article header .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vggB.png)
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <article class="box">

    <header>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vggB.png">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <a href="#"><h1>Lorem Ipsum!</h1></a>
    </header>

    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: what you exactly want to do???

Comment: Hey, I can't get what you mean. Are you going to create text with background color just like the image with the style provided?

Comment: @TonyWu No. It's just a mspaint sketch which does not violate any copyright restrictions ;)

Comment: @TonyWu no reason to downvote. your answer was just a copy of what I **don't** want to do.

Comment: "unclear what you're asking."  Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TonyWu well. not sure what the problem is but I've updated my question. Let me know which part isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Please write following code.That will fix your issue.

You have to write background-size property to 100%.

background-size: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

Put a transparent .png with the same aspect ratio as the image that you want to display in its place. Then set your image as its background image. Like so:

```
.transparent-png {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url('path_to_your_target_image');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Or alternatively, but also a somewhat hacky workaround, you can set the padding-top to: image-height / image-width * container-width [as percentage of page width]. For example, with a 1600*900 image that you want to take up the whole screen:

```
div {
    background-image: url('path_to_my_background_image');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 56.54%;
}
```

If you don't have at least the aspect ratio of the image though, then this isn't possible in CSS.

If you're dealing with unknown images, you could still use the second method, but you would have to use JavaScript to get the heigh/width of the images, and then calculate accordingly.

Comment: Well. I could set the height for the same effect. But I don't know the aspect ratio / should work with every image.

Comment: Different from setting the height, as this will cause the cause the image to preserve aspect ratio - same behavior as an <img> tag.

There's one other way of doing this, but it also requires knowing the aspect ratio, will edit my answer to include.